# dotConnect mobile and fluent nhibernate in compact framework 3.5

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, compact-framework, dotconnect

We are using [dotConnect mobile](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/) for connecting to Oracle DB.

I know that dotConnect can be used with NHibernate and Fluent Nhibernate ORM on the desktop but can the combination also be used with the Compact Framework (version 3.5)?

Comment: read it. If is possible to use dotConnect and Nhibernate in CF 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate cannot be used under the Compact Framework because the Compact Framework does not provide support for some of the fundamental classes (specifically Reflection.Emit)  that NHibernate uses.

1. NHibernate uses Reflection.Emit, which does not exist in the Compact Framework.
2. Because of #1, NHibernate can't be compiled for the Compact Framework.
3. Becasue of #2, we know that there are no Compact Framework compatible NHibernate assemblies.
4. You cannot use desktop assemblies with the Compact Framework. Only assemblies compiled for the CF can be used.

So following this logic we know that *anything* that uses NHibernate will not work under the Compact Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like NHibernate doesn't support .NET Compact Framework due to usage of some Reflection classes.

Comment: Hi, yes i know that. So dotConnect mobile can not be used with Nhibernate in compact Framework 3.5 if i understand correctly?